# Traverse nsdictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am new to swift.
I have my dictionary as

```
monthData = 
{
    "2018-08-10" = {
        accuracy = 71;
        attempted = 7;
        correct = 5;
        reward = Bronze;
    };
    "2018-08-12" = {
        accuracy = 13;
        attempted = 15;
        correct = 2;
        reward = "";
    };
    "2018-08-13" = {
        accuracy = 33;
        attempted = 15;
        correct = 5;
        reward = "";
    };
    "2018-08-14" = {
        accuracy = 100;
        attempted = 15;
        correct = 15;
        reward = Gold;
    };
    "2018-08-16" = {
        accuracy = 73;
        attempted = 15;
        correct = 11;
        reward = Silver;
    };
    "2018-08-21" = {
        accuracy = 26;
        attempted = 15;
        correct = 4;
        reward = "";
    };
    "2018-08-23" = {
        accuracy = 46;
        attempted = 15;
        correct = 7;
        reward = "";
    };
}
```

I want to get all the dates for which `reward` is `Gold`

Can anyone please help me do that?

What I have tried 'till now is:

```
for (key,value) in monthData{
   let temp = monthData.value(forKey: key as! String) as! NSDictionary
   for (key1,value1) in temp{
     if((value1 as! String) == "Gold"){
       print("keyFINAL \(key)")
     }
}
```

but it outputs the error `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber'  to 'NSString'`

Comment: You shouldn't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. What error are you getting?  On which line?

Comment: mention your error??

Comment: edited my summary

Comment: That's because you are enumerating the dictionary `["accuracy": 73, "attempted": 15, "correct":11, "reward": "Silver"]` (for instance), and `thatDict["accuracy"]` (same for value of attempted or correct) is a Int (or NSNumber in case of NSDictionary instead of Swift Dictionary), not a String. So `(value1 as! String)` should obviously causes a crash with that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the first for in loop, you are getting the NSDictionary in temp variable**

```
"2018-08-16" =     {
    accuracy = 73;
    attempted = 15;
    correct = 11;
    reward = Silver;
};
```

**So, you should directly check .value(forKey:) on temp and get the value for reward.**

You should try it like this

```
for (key,value) in monthData {
        let temp = monthData.value(forKey: key as! String) as! NSDictionary
        if(((temp.value(forKey: "reward")) as! String) == "Gold"){
            print("keyFINAL \(key)")
        }
    }
```

Try and share results

**EDIT**

Please checkout the answer from **vadian** for in-depth explanation and pure swift approach to achieve the same.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a note of @Larme 's comment too. Forced downcast of NSNumber objects to NSString will leads to crash. Hope you updated your enum to String type for Gold, Silver and Bronze.

Comment: You ***should not*** use `value(forKey` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed.

Comment: Thanks @vadian for pointing it out. +1 For explaining it in detail with a pure swift approach.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because when you are iterating the dictionary you force cast the `Int` values to `String` which is not possible

The (highly) recommended Swift way is to use the `filter` function. This is much more efficient than a loop.

In the closure `$0.1` represents the `value` of the current dictionary (`$0.0` would be the `key`). The result is an array of the date strings.

```
let data : [String:Any] = ["monthData" : ["2018-08-10": ["accuracy" : 71, "attempted" ... ]]]

if let monthData = data["monthData"] as? [String:[String:Any]] {
    let goldData = monthData.filter { $0.1["reward"] as? String == "Gold" }
    let allDates = Array(goldData.keys)
    print(allDates)
}
```

The code safely unwraps all optionals.

However if there is only **one** Gold entry the `first` function is still more efficient than `filter`

```
if let monthData = data["monthData"] as? [String:[String : Any]] {
    if let goldData = monthData.first( where: {$0.1["reward"] as? String == "Gold" }) {
       let goldDate = goldData.key
        print(goldDate)
    }
}
```

In Swift avoid the ObjC runtime (`value(forKey:)`) and Foundation collection types (`NSDictionary`) as much as possible.